# Как вызвать метод контроллера без показа представления в ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: html, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Хочу вызвать метод (MergeReport) контроллера (Home) для совершения некой фоновой операции. Кроме фоновой операции больше ничего не должно происходить. Вот как это у меня выглядит кнопка во view:

```
 <p>
    <input type="button" value="Create" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("MergeReport", "Home")'" />
 </p>
```

Сам метод во **HomeController.cs**:

```
public void MergeReport()
{
    //...
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("MergeReport start!");                     
}
```

После нажатия на кнопку Create тело MergeReport выполняется, но при этом идет попытка показать представление */Home/MergeReport*. Но мне это не нужно. Необходимо в теле метода MergeReport "фоново" поработать с другими объектами из других классов.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поскольку на событии *"onclick"* у вас используется *location.href*, то автоматически посылается *http-get* запрос и в результате браузер ожидает *html-ответ*. Чтобы совершить фоновую операцию необходимо использовать **асинхронные запросы**. Например, использовать Ajax-запрос из Java-script либо средства Microsoft.ajax.

Самый простой пример jquery ajax.
В контроллере:

```
public EmptyResult MergeReport()
{
   // обращайтесь к любым классам и методам 

   // ничего не возвращаем
   return new EmptyResult();
}
```

Во View:

```
 <script type="text/jscript">
        function CreateMergeReport() {
            $.get("/Home/MergeReport");
        };
 </script>
 <p>
   <input type ="button" onclick="CreateMergeReport()" value="Create"/>
 </p>
```

Так же не забудьте добавить ссылку на скрипт jquery, если в вашем проекте он отсутствует.
Таким образом происходит асинхронный запрос к серверу, страница не переходит на другой url-адрес и не перезагружается. Если обратиться к методу MergeReport через "location.href", то произойдет переход на пустую страницу.

[Другие способы взаимодействия с сервером через jquery Ajax](http://www.itorian.com/2013/02/jquery-ajax-get-and-post-calls-to.html)

Comment: Признаться честно - я новичок в мире `ASP.NET`, да и с `JS` знаком недавно. Вопрос/уточнение: смогу ли через `JS/Ajax` вызвать метод класса `C#`?

Comment: Вы можете вызвать любой POST/GET метод контроллера, а в нем воспроизводить любую логику.
Напрямую вызвать метод неунаследованный от класса Controller не получится.

Comment: @Ice2burn разве только get/post ?

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk новичку знать про PUT/DELETE на первых порах не нужно.